# Oxidation by DMSO

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> 1,2-Butadiene is obtained by oxidation of which compound with DMSO?
>   [image]

I thought that (**A**) will form a aldehyde and (**D**) a ketone. (**C**) will not react will DMSO, and so (**B**) should be the correct answer, but I couldn't get the mechanism and how 1,2-butadiene is formed from (**B**). Any ideas?

Comment: I am completely at a loss of how this is supposed to happen at all. Which is weird.

Comment: 1,2-butadiene??

Answer (score 2):

1,2-Butadiene is an allene (CH3CH=C=CH2); or was the name supposed to be 1,3-butadiene? Both are C4 compounds. C and D are eliminated because they are both C5 compounds. Compound A and B are both C4. Compound A, 1-bromobutane, would yield, in the presence of NaHCO3/DMSO at elevated temperatures, n-butyraldehyde (Kornblum Oxidation, 1959). Conceptually, compound B could provide 2-butanone by the same oxidation. While both of the carbonyl compounds are at the same oxidation level as either diene, I have severe reservations that either diene is formed.